# Javascript can't click() on an <input type="button"> in Chrome

Tags: javascript, selenium, click, webdriver

I have a button who's code is as follows:

```
<input type="button" onclick="someFunction();" value="doSomething">
```

I am trying to click on this button in Selenium2. I manage to get the element, but the click() function does not work in Chrome.

I tried to do it on JavaScript directly, but it still doesn't work in Chrome.

It works if you click directly on the button, and it also works in Firefox.

Anyone has any idea on how to fix this?

Edit: I had forgotten the brackets in my example. They're present in the "real" code.

Edit2: The Selenium 2 code used to simulate the click is:

```
driver.findElement(By.tagName("input")).click();
```

Before somebody asks, there is no other tagName "input" in the page.

Comment: @dystroy I can't imagine removing the semicolon would help. It still wouldn't be called, would it?

Comment: Try modifying your code to this: `<input type="button" onclick="someFunction();" value="doSomething" />`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally speaking, using inline attributes to define event handlers is a bad idea. Instead you should opt for binding event handlers using JavaScript so that your content (HTML) and functionality (JavaScript) are separated.

However, the problem seems to be that you're not actually calling the function. Change it to:

```
<input type="button" onclick="someFunction();" value="doSomething">
```

Comment: +1, especially for reminding the OP to avoid inline event handlers.

Comment: Might want to provide an alternative to inline event handlers if you're going to tell OP to avoid them.

Comment: @arxanas Agreed, just trying to find a decent guide to binding events using regular JavaScript.

Comment: And why are inline event handlers bad?

Comment: @ianpgall They mix together the structure — HTML — and the behavior — Javascript — of your code, which makes it hard to read and difficult to maintain/extend.

Comment: +1, Totally correct, what I want to know is how Firefox was working :) ??

Comment: @FishBasketGordo Can you please tell what is "OP"?? Is it slang for some word

Comment: OP == Original Poster, i.e. the person who asked the question.

Answer (score 1):

i think you have to use function name with function brackets()

like this 
input type="button" **onclick="someFunction();**" value="doSomething"

i hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, or even better put javascript in separate file:

```
<input type="button" value="doSomething" id="someFuncBtn">

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#someFuncBtn').on('click', function(){
            someFunction();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I realised that it was a problem with the click, that works a bit oddly sometimes. It works better this way:

```
driver.findElements(By.tagName("input")).get(0).click();
```

Even though it still fails "sometimes". I still have no idea why though.